# During Haystack update_index: 'Result window is too large, from + size must be less than or equal to: [10000] but was [10100]

Tags: elasticsearch, django-haystack

I have django-haystack 2.6.1 and Elasticsearch 2.4.6. I have an index of about 200k documents, and during the `update_index` with 8 workers and batch size of 100, I get the following error:

`Failed to query Elasticsearch using '*:*': TransportError(500, u'search_phase_execution_exception', u'Result window is too large, from + size must be less than or equal to: [10000] but was [10100]. See the scroll api for a more efficient way to request large data sets. This limit can be set by changing the [index.max_result_window] index level parameter.')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/haystack/backends/elasticsearch_backend.py", line 524, in search
    _source=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/elasticsearch/client/utils.py", line 73, in _wrapped
    return func(*args, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/elasticsearch/client/__init__.py", line 623, in search
    doc_type, '_search'), params=params, body=body)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/elasticsearch/transport.py", line 312, in perform_request
    status, headers, data = connection.perform_request(method, url, params, body, ignore=ignore, timeout=timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/elasticsearch/connection/http_urllib3.py", line 128, in perform_request
    self._raise_error(response.status, raw_data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/elasticsearch/connection/base.py", line 125, in _raise_error
    raise HTTP_EXCEPTIONS.get(status_code, TransportError)(status_code, error_message, additional_info)
TransportError: TransportError(500, u'search_phase_execution_exception', u'Result window is too large, from + size must be less than or equal to: [10000] but was [10100]. See the scroll api for a more efficient way to request large data sets. This limit can be set by changing the [index.max_result_window] index level parameter.')`

I don't think I want to simply make the result window larger, because it feels like simply cheating the problem. It also sounds like Haystack is querying by `result_window + my_batch_size`, so it's not coincidental.

Is this a known issue? Any idea how to fix it?

My command was:

```
./manage.py update_index --remove -k 8 --batch-size=100
```

Thanks.

Comment: Issue https://github.com/django-haystack/django-haystack/issues/1507